# since macOS Ventura (13.0) appleScript don't work with contacts

Tags: applescript, contacts, macos-ventura

-- Code
tell application "Contacts"
set cc to count of people
display dialog cc
end tell

-- Answer
Skriptfehler
Keine Berechtigung zum Senden von Apple-Events an Contacts.

I can not add in the security-settings the Scripteditor??

Where is the bug?? (I think in the new software-release).

Answer (score 0):

Your script works for me on Catalina, but it's always best to stick to the AppleScript rules to avoid unexpected issues with system updates.

Better, place both **count** command and **display dialog** command out of Contact's **tell block**. Because both of them are not Contact.app commands (**count** is not property of people as well to use syntax "of people"). The **display dialog** expects some text value for its parameter, so it is better to apply explicit coercion for counting result (which is an integer). At least on my Catalina following works:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set personsList to people

set cc to count personsList
display dialog (cc as text)
```

If the **people** is broken on Ventura, maybe **every person** will work:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set personsList to every person

set cc to count personsList
display dialog (cc as text)
```

Also, try to add the keyword **its** before **people**. Sometimes this helps with conflict solving.

Sometimes helps providing app constant and compiling at runtime as well:

```
set personConstant to "«class azf4»"

set personsList to run script "tell application \"Contacts\" to every " & personConstant

set cc to count personsList
display dialog (cc as text)
```

Now, if nothing works, try following script in the **Script Debugger** to see what structure has the application on Ventura. It will show you what is broken as well. Open variable **contactsApp** in Variables window to see what happens:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set contactsApp to it
```

One last suggestion. Go to **Security&Privacy** pane of **System Preferences**, click on **Contacts**, see if your script editor is in applications which has **access to Contacts**. If not then add it, in other case - remove it than add again.